# How to handle order of fields in groupby line based on user's selection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like that in Sql Server 2008:

```
Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3)...
from Table
group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD
```

What I need to do is to change the column order in the `GroupBy` line based on user's demand. For example, **User1** wants to see the results: `group by ColumnB, ColumnA, ColumnD, ColumnC`, where **User2** wants to see the results: `group by ColumnD, ColumnA, ColumnC, ColumnB`. Basically, the order in the groupby segment should be dynamic based on user's selection. There are 24 potential order...

What is the best way to handle it?

I came up with an idea like:

```
declare @groupbyOrder int = 20 --let's say 20
Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3)...
from Table
group by (case when @groupbyOrder = 1 then ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD)
               ...
               when @groupbyOrder = 20 then ColumnD, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnA)
               ...)
```

But it did not work and I don't think it is a good way to manage the issue. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why do you think that the order of columns in the group by makes any difference anyway? If you are grouping by the same columns it doesn't matter what order the columns appear in the group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another Dynamic SQL option where you the selected columns may include expressions and thus your group/order by will exclude the alias.

**Example**

```
Declare @Cols varchar(max)
Declare @GroupOrder varchar(max)
Declare @SQL varchar(max)

Select @Cols = Cols
      ,@GroupOrder = isnull(GroupOrder,Cols)
 From  (values (1,'ColA,ColB',null)                                          -- Notice GrpBy is null
              ,(2,'ColA,ColB=cast(ColB as date)','ColA,cast(ColB as date)')  -- can include expressions
               -- Add more otions here
       ) A(ID,Cols,GroupOrder)
  Where ID=2

Set @SQL = '
Select '+@Cols +',sum(value1),sum(value)
 From  Table
 Group By '+@GroupOrder +'
 Order By '+@GroupOrder

Print @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```

**Generated SQL**

```
Select ColA,ColB=cast(ColB as date),sum(value1),sum(value)
 From  Table
 Group By ColA,cast(ColB as date)
 Order By ColA,cast(ColB as date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Huh?  The `group by` doesn't need to change, only the `select`.  The order by expressions in a `group by` has no effect on what the result set looks like.

This is very strange request, but I think four variables make more sense than 1:

```
Select (case when @firstColumn = 'A' then ColumnA
             when @firstColumn = 'B' then ColumnB
             . . .
        end) as firstcolumn,
       (case when @secondColumn = 'A' then ColumnA
             when @secondCOlumn = 'B' then ColumnB
             . . .
        end) as secondcolumn,
       . . .
       sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3)...
from Table t
group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD;
```

My guess is that you really care about `order by` -- `group by` rows are in an arbitrary order.  If so, you should ask another question with sample data and an explanation of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Grodon's comment, you can use dynamic sql to build the sql statement using the user's selected preference.

Get the user's preferred order as a string, such as

```
'group by Column1,Column2'
```

Then append that to your static query text,

```
'Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3) from Table'
```

and execute the final statement:

```
'Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3) from Table' + 'group by Column1,Column2'
```